# Xamarin EventTrigger c# code

Tags: c#, xamarin, triggers

I have this trigger in my XAML page:

```
<Entry.Triggers>
   <EventTrigger Event="TextChanged">
     <core:NumericValidationTrigger />
   </EventTrigger>
</Entry.Triggers>
```

How can I do the same thing in C# code?
I'm done this:

```
EventTrigger ETrigger = new EventTrigger {
    Event = "TextChanged"
 };
 Triggers.Add(ETrigger);
```

But how can I attach to `ETrigger` to run `NumericValidationTrigger`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it to the  `Actions` of EventTrigger.

```
public class NumericValidationTriggerAction : TriggerAction<Entry>
{
    protected override void Invoke(Entry entry)
    {
        double result;
        bool isValid = Double.TryParse(entry.Text, out result);
        entry.BackgroundColor =
              isValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;
    }
}

EventTrigger ETrigger = new EventTrigger
{
    Event = "TextChanged"
};
ETrigger.Actions.Add(new NumericValidationTriggerAction());
entry.Triggers.Add(ETrigger);
```